What was the old sailing ship where the captain and pilot famously disagreed on a navigation decision and the ship soon sank?
I remember a high school history story where a 1500s -1700s era sailing / exploring ship grounded on a shoal and broke up over the course of several days (with survivors) after the pilot and captain had previously disagreed on a navigation decision, and one of them ceremoniously "washed his hands of the decision" in front of the crew.
Searching Google with short descriptions like "ship sank after pilot washed his hands of navigation decision" brings up Pilate. In this case, due to survivor stories, the ceremonious hand washing of accountability for the decision was well documented.

Since this is between a captain and a pilot, this would have to have occurred in the vicinity of an established port or anchorage. Established practice would have the captain defer to the pilot (who was employed because of his local knowledge). So it would be extraordinary to have them come into conflict about a navigation decision.

In general, we discourage "Some drunk in a bar told me" stories.  Also I believe (?) we have a site policy that AI content cannot be used as the basis for a question, as it is unreliable, so I've removed that bit. Might as well just assume it completely made up what it told you. I'd much prefer to see an actual link to someone else actually having heard this story.

@MCW - Well...some are better than others. For me if there are enough details (like specific people's names perhaps), it could probably be looked at. This one seems on the weak side to me, but perhaps someone can find a handle on it that I cannot.

Granted - Deleted my observation.  Like Steve Bird, I'm fixated on where a captain and pilot would disagree.

@Jeff Brower Ric Wharton, The Salvage of the Century, 2000, p. 137: "After three weeks of painfully slow progress, a major dispute broke out between the captain and the pilots as to the ship's position. The captain felt that they were much too far west and wished to sail east for another week, but the pilots insisted that they were now due north of Puerto Rico and wanted to turn south at once. Under the law, the pilots prevailed. The captain called for a silver bowl of water to be brought on deck and washed his hands in public in front of the crew as the ship turned south to its doom ...

@Jeff Brower "... On the night of October 31, the Conception grounded on the dreaded Abrojos reef to the north of Hispaniola. She grounded in fine weather, but the crew was unable to get her off before the weather got up and drove her further onto the reef, where she rapidly started to break up. They had only one ship's boat left after the storm , so the captain gave orders to build rafts ..." I don't have access to the book. The story may be about the Nuestra Señora de la Concepción, a Spanish galleon that sank in 1641.

This is probably an infinite list question.

@T.E.D. I would suggest keeping the question open. I found what looks like a credible lead (see comments above).

@Jeff Brower Most of the information about Concepción is contained in books, of which only fragments are publicly available via Google. From what I could find, the ship's captain was admiral Don Juan de Villavicencio, and the pilot he had a disagreement with regarding the ship's position was Bartolome Guillen.

@nJuffa, yes you found it. An extensive description is here. The detail about the captain,  literally and symbolically" washing his hands of responsibility, and this option being in the maritime laws of the time, is what we were taught that day many years ago. For anyone wondering, this came to mind when I read today about an Intel board of director resigning, and his stated reasons why. If you can make short answer I can accept it. Thanks

@TED first it was not a drunk in a bar, it was a well respected high school history teacher. Second the Google and  ChatGPT research results I mentioned were not the basis of my question, they are evidence of my efforts to find the answer. My understanding of stackexchange and and stackoverflow is that diligent level of effort before posting a question is required, so I am trying to adhere to the rules.  If that's no longer the case, then please clarify.

@Jeff Brower Sorry, I will refrain from writing an answer as maritime history is outside my area of expertise. Now that we have identified the relevant event, someone who is knowledgeable about these matters should be able to provide a great answer.

There are many stories like this. Probably the most famous (but not coinciding with the one you are recalling) is
the disaster on October 22 1707, when the British fleet
of 21 ships under Admiral Cloudesley Shovell hit the rock West
of Scilly islands with the loss of more than 1000 sailors,
including the admiral himself. (The admiral swam to the shore and was killed by a local robber).
The weather was cloudy, and they could not determine their latitude by astronomical observations.
They missed the entrance to the English channel. A day before
one of the navigators of the fleet insisted that their dead reconing is wrong, but he was punished for contradicting the admiral's orders.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scilly_naval_disaster_of_1707

The linked Wikipedia article discredits both the tale of the punished sailor and the murder of the Admiral.

@Alex Thanks. Yes I found that one also during my search too. The La Concepcion is the answer. There were several survivors in different groups all with a similar story. Even the subsequent treasure hunters (Phips, Webber, et. al). have added corroboration. In retrospect I think this level of detail may be why my history teacher chose that example to teach something about decision making and leadership. I studied engineering in college and didn't have enough respect for history at the time but over the years I have changed my perspective completely !
